# How to debug code that was attached to a .exe

Tags: c++, debugging, adobe-indesign

I'm developing a plugin for InDesign CS5.5. And when developing a plugin you can't really debug if you don't have the debug version of the program you're developing for(in my case, indesign). 
I tried to get the debug version from adobe with no success. A lot of bureaucracy.

So my question is: Is there a way to attach a debugger(or something else) so I can see where the code is going to?

I'm really tired of typing "MessageBox".

Thanks in advance.

For indesign plugin development c++ is used by the way.

Comment: Have you tried attaching visual studio's debugger to the InDesign process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your plug-in is a dll that's loaded dynamically, you can attach Visual Studio to the process, set breakpoints, and step into your dll's code. To attach to an existing process, just go to debug -> attach to existing process, or try the shortcut `Ctrl+Alp+P` IIRC.

Comment: well, it's built in the same way as a dll (cause the output is shown as .dll in the project properties). Well, i'll try to find a step-by-step.

Comment: @PatrickBassut what do you mean a step-by-step? If you attach to the process the way I mentioned, you'll be able to debug the dll.

Comment: yeah, it worked. And step-by-step i meant see the eip going line-by-line. Sorry, bad english. And thanks.